# React native, variable from one component to other

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-component

i need help in React Native :
As you see in pic, i have contactlist in contacts.js and i would like to get this parameter in start.js. These are two components in Component Folder. Is there any way to get this?
I appreciate any kind of help.
I am using Expo v4.4.8[image]

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet of the problem?

Comment: I think you should start by reading some getting started documentation for React Native (the docs are very good about this). It sounds like you are having this problem because of a misunderstanding of how React's state works. If you need access to a components state outside of itself then it shouldn't be in that components state (but rather in the parent component and passed down)